# custom logs in docker

Tags: docker, docker-machine

I need to get the logs from the running container persisted on the host, so we don't lose the logs when the container restarts.

The logs that get put in the standard apache logs are handled fine with the `--log-driver=syslog --log-opt syslog-tag="app_name"` run options.  However, each application also has a custom *debug.log* output.

I tried using the `--log-opt syslog-address=unix://infra/py/appinstance/app/log/debug.log` run parameter, but that doesn't work.  I would like to plug the debug logs into the standard syslog, but I don't see how to do it.  Any ideas.

Comment: where is located the custom debug.log? is it possible to put it in a directory that you mount with `docker run -v `?

Answer (score 4):

the `docker run`[`--log-driver`](https://docs.docker.com/reference/logging/overview/) option is to specify where to store your docker container log. The log we are talking about here is the one that you get from the [`docker logs`](https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/logs/) command.

The content of that log is gathered from the container's process **standard output** and **error output**.

The *debug.log* file you are mentioning isn't sent to any of the standard or error output and has such won't be handled by docker.

---

You have at least two options to persist those debug messages:

#### writing to stdout or stderr

You can make your application write its debug messages to the standard or error output instead of to the *debug.log* file. This way those debug messages will be handled by docker, and given the `--log-driver=syslog` option will persist in your host syslog service.

#### mount a volume

You can also use the `docker run` [`-v`](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/) option to create a volume in your container that will mount a directory from your docker host in your container.
Then configure your application so that it writes the *debug.log* file on that mount point.